# .htaccess; How to redirect all that are containing specific parameter an subdirectory

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

How can I redirect all URL that contain `value=123` and `something` to `/maintenance.php`?

Redirect e.g.:

```
www.example.com/something/myfile.php?value=123
www.example.com/something/thisfile.php?value=123
```

Don't redirect e.g.

```
www.example.com/something/myfile.php?value=999
www.example.com/something/myfile.php?test=999
www.example.com/folder/myfile.php?value=123
```

How can I do this with `.htacces`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this redirect rule to match a specific URI with a specific `QUERY_STRING`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+something/[^?]*\?value=123[&\s] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /maintenance.php? [R=302,L]
```